# windows 10 right click, shut down/restart etc not working

Tags: windows, windows-10

A few days ago Reaper (https://www.reaper.fm/) stopped opening its native files (it hung while loading VSTs). At the same time I noticed that right click stopped working on the desktop and in windows explorer. Also, "shut down/restart etc" from the start menu also stopped working.

The previous day I had installed Adobe Lightroom through Adobe creative cloud (which also updated). I removed Adobe Lightroom and nothing changed. I also checked regedit Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ for anything out of the ordinary - there wasnt.

I could remove Adobe Creative Cloud (but Id prefer not to since I'll need to remove Adobe Photoshop too).... before I do does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Start by undoing what you did before the problem started. That's always a good first step.